# Excel - Choose Item from a List

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to select an Excel item from a list -- when that list is in a single cell -- using predefined functions, or if I'm going to have to write my own VBA to make it happen.

Something similar to the `=CHOOSE()` function seems to be what I need, as it works if all of the values are in separate cells:

<kbd>**A**</kbd>                            <kbd>**B**</kbd>                       
<kbd>**1**</kbd><kbd>alpha</kbd>  <kbd>=CHOOSE(2,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5)</kbd>
<kbd>**2**</kbd><kbd>beta</kbd>                                                     
<kbd>**3**</kbd><kbd>gamma</kbd>                                                 
<kbd>**4**</kbd><kbd>delta</kbd>                                                     
<kbd>**5**</kbd><kbd>epsilon</kbd>

The formula above in cell **B1** gives me exactly the value I expect: "beta".

But the way my source data are constructed, the values are all in the same cell:

<kbd>**A**</kbd>                                   <kbd>**B**</kbd>             
<kbd>**1**</kbd><kbd>alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon</kbd><kbd>=CHOOSE(2,A1)</kbd>

And in this construction, the forumula in **B1** results in a `#VALUE!` error. I *do* understand why this error occurs -- but I'm wondering if there is either:

1. Some way to make Excel interpret the comma-separated values in cell **A1** as five separate values, or
2. Some alternate function I should be using to accomplish this goal.

If Excel can't handle it, I'll write my own function -- but it seems like such a straightforward need that I assume the program has it built in somewhere.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/483419/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-in-ms-excel

Comment: I don´t know, but if there is a direct function for this task, you can write a VBA Macro to Split(sourceText, separator)  http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_split_function.html

Comment: So in other words you want to enter a number (n), 2 in your example, and return the word before the nth comma and after the nth-1 from your source cell?

Comment: user2140261: Yes, that sums up my intention. I can certainly write my own function if there's no predefined function in Excel to do it -- I just didn't want to overlook something.

Comment: To get the nth item in a csv, for example the **second** item   =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))       change the **2** to suit your needs

Comment: Gary's Student: Very slick! Since there doesn't seem to be a predefined function that does what I'm looking for, I'll mark this as correct if you want to submit it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent 's example will work on small lists but the bigger the list, the more likely his will result in an overload of a cells capacity (replcing to many commas with 999 spaces for each comma will limit your list to 65 values if all values are a single character long), if you need a longer list then you can use `=MID(A1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",C1-1))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",C1))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","~",C1-1))-1)` Where C1 contains the index of the word you are trying to get.

Comment: I get that -- but I can reduce the number of spaces based on my familiarity with the data. Her/his solution gives me a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have csv list in A1 then run this macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With Range("B1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=Range("A1").Value
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you click on your cell you want to split and click "Data > Text to Columns" then you can split the data at the comma into separate cells. Then you can use your Choose formula that you are used to using.

Within the Text to Columns function you will want to specifically choose the "Delimited" option on the first page and then choose "Comma" on the second page if your data appears exactly as you have in your example above.