# adding cells with string functions in excel

Tags: string, excel

I'm setting up a spreadsheet for Martial Art Instructors to enter and calculate grading scores

I have two sheets set up in excel.

The first is where the instructor enters a letter value (A, B, C, D, E, F) for each technique for each student who has done the test.

I am trying set up the second sheet to automatically calculate the numeric value of each letter, and then sum it up at the bottom of the column.

I've made this function for each cell:

=IF('Enter Scores'!B7="D", "3",IF('Enter Scores'!B7="B","5.10",IF('Enter Scores'!B7="C","4.50",IF('Enter Scores'!B7="E","1.50",IF('Enter Scores'!B7="F","0",IF('Enter Scores'!B7="A,"6"))))))

Basically each letter has a number value, if A is entered  to B7 on the first sheet then the number 6 should show up on the current sheet in the appropriate cell.

I can't use a =SUM(B6:B12) function because the numbers aren't really 'numbers' according to excel (i'm assuming).

I've changed the format of each cell to 'number'; but I can't seem to get them to add up; I only get a total of 0.00 - when I enter a number in from scratch in the same cells the sum function works fine.

Each cell has the same function, but shows a different result, I need to get all those different results to be added to a total.

Maybe I need to use another function entirely.....

Comment: The nested if statement is hard to read and hard to maintain. I would recommend that you use the CHOOSE function (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640927/excel-choose-item-from-a-list) or the VLOOKUP function (answer follows).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by returning a number.  This example returns 15.5 for me.  You can use this as an example for the rest of your conditions.

```
=IF(E11="C",4.5)+11
```

Notice that I don't quote my 4.5.

Comment: Hi, thanks, 
I don't think I said the word 'returning' in my question....

I attempted to remove the quotation marks but excel is notifying me of a formula error and then it highlights "C"... i can't see anything wrong with it, and I didn't change that.

Comment: If you can reproduce what I see, you probably have something extraneous in your other cell you claim has 'C' in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use a table and the built-in Excel function, `VLOOKUP`.

I first converted your if statement to scores in a table, and then had the "gradebook" read from that table.

Here is the table in A1 through B7:

```
Gr  Score
A   6
B   5.1
C   4.5
D   3
E   1.5
F   0
```

Here is the "gradebook." I am placing them in A9 through C11:

```
Who Grade   Score
Bill    B   5.1
Sheila  A   6
```

The secret sauce is what goes in "Score" at C10 and C11. In C10, for Bill, type the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B10,$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE)
```

What this says is: given the grade in B10, look up that grade in A2 through A7 and return column 2 (the Score) and give an exact match (that's what the `FALSE` is for).

You may copy-down the formula for Sheila and the rest of the students. If there is no match (for example, if you put "Incomplete" in column B) then you would get an Excel error, `#N/A`. If you would rather have a 0 there, replace the `FALSE` in the VLOOKUP with a `TRUE`.